# Swift - Request status was 400 while uploading Video to Twitter

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I am trying to upload i.e. Share a video using my device to twitter. I have used the below code so far to do that.

```
     // video Upload

    func requestAccessToTwitterAccount(videoURL:NSURL,fileSize:UInt32){

        let accountStore = ACAccountStore()
        let twitterAccountType = accountStore.accountType(withAccountTypeIdentifier: ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter)
        accountStore.requestAccessToAccounts(with: twitterAccountType, options: nil) { (granted, error) in

            if granted {
                let accounts = accountStore.accounts(with: twitterAccountType)
                if (accounts?.count)! > 0 {
                    self.twitterAccount = accounts?.last as! ACAccount
                    self.uploadVideoToTwitter(videoURL: videoURL, fileSize: fileSize)
                }
            else{
                    let error = "Please set your twitter account in Settings."
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        else {
            print("App permissions are disabled in device twitter settings, please enable it.")
        }
    }
}
    func uploadVideoToTwitter(videoURL:NSURL,fileSize: UInt32){
        print(videoURL.path!)
        if let videoData = NSData(contentsOfFile: videoURL.path!){

            self.tweetVideoInit(videoData: videoData, videoSize: Int(fileSize))
        }else{
            print("Something Wrong")
        }
    }

    func tweetVideoInit(videoData:NSData,videoSize:Int) {

        let uploadURL = NSURL(string:"https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json")

        var params = [String:String]()

        params["command"] = "INIT"
        params["total_bytes"]  = String(videoData.length)
        params["media_type"]  = "video/MOV"

        print(params)

        let postRequest = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter,
                                    requestMethod: SLRequestMethod.POST,
                                    url: uploadURL as URL!,
                                    parameters: params)

        postRequest?.account = self.twitterAccount;

        postRequest?.perform(handler: { ( responseData, urlREsponse,error) in
            if let err = error {
                print(error!)
            }else{
                do {
                    let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData! as Data, options: .allowFragments)
                    if let dictionary = object as? [String: AnyObject] {

                        if let tweetID = dictionary["media_id_string"] as? String{
                            self.tweetVideoApped(videoData: videoData, videoSize: videoSize, mediaId: tweetID, chunk: 0)
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        })
    }



    func tweetVideoApped(videoData:NSData,videoSize:Int ,mediaId:String,chunk:NSInteger) {

        let uploadURL = NSURL(string:"https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json")

        var params = [String:String]()

        params["command"] = "APPEND"
        params["media_id"]  = mediaId
        params["segment_index"]  = String(chunk)

        print(params)

        let postRequest = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter,
                                    requestMethod: SLRequestMethod.POST,
                                    url: uploadURL as URL!,
                                    parameters: params)

        postRequest?.account = self.twitterAccount;
        postRequest?.addMultipartData(videoData as Data!, withName: "media", type: "video/mov", filename:"mediaFile")

        postRequest?.perform(handler: { ( responseData, urlREsponse,error) in
            if let err = error {
                print(err)

            }else{
                self.tweetVideoFinalize(mediaId: mediaId)
            }
        })
    }

    func tweetVideoFinalize(mediaId:String) {
        let uploadURL = NSURL(string:"https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json")

        var params = [String:String]()
        params["command"] = "FINALIZE"
        params["media_id"]  = mediaId

        let postRequest = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter,
                                    requestMethod: SLRequestMethod.POST,
                                    url: uploadURL as URL!,
                                    parameters: params)

        postRequest?.account = self.twitterAccount;
        postRequest?.perform(handler: { ( responseData, urlREsponse,error) in
            if let err = error {
                print(err)
            }else{
                do {
                    let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData! as Data, options: .allowFragments)
                    if let dictionary = object as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        self.postStatus(mediaId: mediaId)
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        })
    }

    func postStatus(mediaId:String) {

        let uploadURL = NSURL(string:"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json")

        var params = [String:String]()
        //params["status"] = twitterDescription
        params["media_ids"]  = mediaId

        let postRequest = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter,
                                    requestMethod: SLRequestMethod.POST,
                                    url: uploadURL as URL!,
                                    parameters: params)

        postRequest?.account = self.twitterAccount;

        postRequest?.perform(handler: { ( responseData, urlREsponse,error) in

            if let err = error {
                print(err)
            }else{
                do {
                    let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData! as Data, options: .allowFragments)
                    if let dictionary = object as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        print("video uploaded")
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "video uploaded successfully.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Now the issue is like this, I am not sure where the problem is but when i try to upload a video of less then `10 secs` it is uploaded **successfully**, but when i try a video more that 10 sec it gives a error with **Request status 400** and video does not upload.

**Note:-** My video format is **`.MOV`** and size is around **6.4MB**. so i guess it is accepted according to the guidelines of the `Twitter` for video uploading.

**FYI:-** I have also referred this link - [Twitter Upload Demo](http://swiftoverflow.blogspot.in/2017/04/upload-video-to-twitter-using-slrequest.html)

> Also the [Official Documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/overview) Suggests following limits, which
>   i do not exceed.

[image]

Can someone help me with this why this issue is occurring.

Comment: Http code 400 is a 'Bad Request'. So the request you are sending is not valid for the API. Maybe missing parameters, file size too big etc. Have you searched Stackoverflow for answers already? This has been asked a number of times before.

Comment: Yes @Scriptable  have searched for this, They have suggested that the parameters are wrong, but in my case they are not as they are working in 6-7 sec videos but not in 10+ sec videos.? So i guess the issue is something different

Comment: So i guess you are hitting API limits. if it works for small videos but not for larger videos then you must be hitting upload/rate limits.

Comment: Yes i may agree with you on this point, but i have read in some of the forums that this seems to be in case of .mov format only and size is not an issue because if i upload the video using an URL then it is easily uploaded, if it is of 20+ seconds then also. So can you please explain why this happens

Comment: Im not a twitter API developer, maybe you should contact them for support

Comment: Any of them who is due this error  command `INIT` , `APPEND` or `FINALIZE` ?

Comment: Sorry i did not understand, what you said @a.masri ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching the [Docs](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/wiki/Installation) and not finding any way. The thing which worked for me is like `Compressing` the Video.

I used the following code to compress the video and convert it to `.m4v` Format and some how it worked for me.

> **Note:-** The limit for uploading a video is **15MB** and **30sec** Max

The complete code for uploading a video to `Twitter` is:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    if  let video = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL{
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: video)
        let durationInSeconds = asset.duration.seconds
        print(durationInSeconds)

        if durationInSeconds < 30{
            arrImageURL.removeAll()
            btnSelectImage.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .normal)
            btnSelectImage.setTitle("Select Image to attach", for: .normal)
            videoURL = video
            print(videoURL)
            let innerVideoURL = video
            let data = NSData(contentsOf: innerVideoURL as URL)!
            print("File size before compression: \(Double(data.length / 1048576)) mb")
            let compressedURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + NSUUID().uuidString + ".m4v")
            compressVideo(inputURL: innerVideoURL , outputURL: compressedURL) { (exportSession) in
                guard let session = exportSession else {
                    return
                }

                switch session.status {
                case .unknown:
                    break
                case .waiting:
                    break
                case .exporting:
                    break
                case .completed:
                    self.videoURL = compressedURL
                case .failed:
                    break
                case .cancelled:
                    break
                }
            }
        }else{
            showAlertWithTitle(title: "Alert!", message: "Video Length cannot be more that 30Sec to upload!")
        }

    }
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
}

func compressVideo(inputURL: URL, outputURL: URL, handler:@escaping (_ exportSession: AVAssetExportSession?)-> Void) {
        let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: inputURL, options: nil)
        guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: urlAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality) else {
            handler(nil)
            return
        }

        exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov
        exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        exportSession.exportAsynchronously { () -> Void in
            handler(exportSession)
        }
    }
```

**Then Call the Following methods in Sequence to upload a Video:**

```
    // video Upload

    func requestAccessToTwitterAccount(videoURL:NSURL,fileSize:UInt32){

        let accountStore = ACAccountStore()
        let twitterAccountType = accountStore.accountType(withAccountTypeIdentifier: ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter)
        accountStore.requestAccessToAccounts(with: twitterAccountType, options: nil) { (granted, error) in

            if granted {
                let accounts = accountStore.accounts(with: twitterAccountType)
                if (accounts?.count)! > 0 {
                    self.twitterAccount = accounts?.last as! ACAccount
                    self.uploadVideoToTwitter(videoURL: videoURL, fileSize: fileSize)
                }
            else{
                    let error = "Please set your twitter account in Settings."
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        else {
            print("App permissions are disabled in device twitter settings, please enable it.")
        }
    }
}
    func uploadVideoToTwitter(videoURL:NSURL,fileSize: UInt32){
        print(videoURL.path!)
        if let videoData = NSData(contentsOfFile: videoURL.path!){

            self.tweetVideoInit(videoData: videoData, videoSize: Int(fileSize))
        }else{
            print("Something Wrong")
        }
    }

    func tweetVideoInit(videoData:NSData,videoSize:Int) {

        let uploadURL = NSURL(string:"https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json")

        var params = [String:String]()

        params["command"] = "INIT"
        params["total_bytes"]  = String(videoData.length)
        params["media_type"]  = "video/m4v"

        print(params)

        let postRequest = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter,
                                    requestMethod: SLRequestMethod.POST,
                                    url: uploadURL as URL!,
                                    parameters: params)

        postRequest?.account = self.twitterAccount;

        postRequest?.perform(handler: { ( responseData, urlREsponse,error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            }else{
                do {
                    let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData! as Data, options: .allowFragments)
                    if let dictionary = object as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        print(dictionary)
                        if let tweetID = dictionary["media_id_string"] as? String{
                            self.tweetVideoApped(videoData: videoData, videoSize: videoSize, mediaId: tweetID, chunk: 0)
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        })
    }



    func tweetVideoApped(videoData:NSData,videoSize:Int ,mediaId:String,chunk:NSInteger) {

        let uploadURL = NSURL(string:"https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json")

        var params = [String:String]()

        params["command"] = "APPEND"
        params["media_id"]  = mediaId
        params["segment_index"]  = String(chunk)

        print(params)

        let postRequest = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter,
                                    requestMethod: SLRequestMethod.POST,
                                    url: uploadURL as URL!,
                                    parameters: params)

        postRequest?.account = self.twitterAccount;
        postRequest?.addMultipartData(videoData as Data!, withName: "media", type: "video/m4v", filename:"mediaFile")

        postRequest?.perform(handler: { ( responseData, urlREsponse,error) in
            print(responseData!)
            if let err = error {
                print(err)

            }else{
                self.tweetVideoFinalize(mediaId: mediaId)
            }
        })
    }

    func tweetVideoFinalize(mediaId:String) {
        let uploadURL = NSURL(string:"https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json")

        var params = [String:String]()
        params["command"] = "FINALIZE"
        params["media_id"]  = mediaId

         print(params)

        let postRequest = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter,
                                    requestMethod: SLRequestMethod.POST,
                                    url: uploadURL as URL!,
                                    parameters: params)

        postRequest?.account = self.twitterAccount;
        postRequest?.perform(handler: { ( responseData, urlREsponse,error) in
            print(responseData!)
            if let err = error {
                print(err)
            }else{
                do {
                    let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData! as Data, options: .allowFragments)
                    if let dictionary = object as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        print(dictionary)
                        if self.videoURL != nil{
                            self.postStatusVideo(mediaId: mediaId)
                        }else{
                            print("Image Post Called")
                            if self.arrMediaIdString.count == self.arrImage.count{
                                self.postStatusMultipleImages(arrMediaId: self.arrMediaIdString, statusText: "Demo Multi Images")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        })
    }

    func postStatusMultipleImages(arrMediaId:[String],statusText:String) {

        let uploadURL = NSURL(string:"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json")

        var params = [String:Any]()
        params["status"] = statusText
        params["media_ids"]  = arrMediaId

        print(params)

        let postRequest = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter,
                                    requestMethod: SLRequestMethod.POST,
                                    url: uploadURL as URL!,
                                    parameters: params)

        postRequest?.account = self.twitterAccount;

        postRequest?.perform(handler: { ( responseData, urlREsponse,error) in
            print(responseData!)
            if let err = error {
                print(err)
            }else{
                do {
                    let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData! as Data, options: .allowFragments)
                    if let dictionary = object as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        print(dictionary)
                        print("video uploaded")
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "video uploaded successfully.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        })
    }

    func postStatusVideo(mediaId:String) {

        let uploadURL = NSURL(string:"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json")

        var params = [String:String]()
        params["status"] = "Testing Video"
        params["media_ids"]  = mediaId

         print(params)

        let postRequest = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter,
                                    requestMethod: SLRequestMethod.POST,
                                    url: uploadURL as URL!,
                                    parameters: params)

        postRequest?.account = self.twitterAccount;

        postRequest?.perform(handler: { ( responseData, urlREsponse,error) in
           print(responseData!)
            if let err = error {
                print(err)
            }else{
                do {
                    let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData! as Data, options: .allowFragments)
                    if let dictionary = object as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        print(dictionary)
                        print("video uploaded")
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "video uploaded successfully.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

**And finally Use it like This:**

```
var fileSizeValue = getVideoSize(contentUrl: videoURL)
requestAccessToTwitterAccount(videoURL: videoURL as NSURL, fileSize: UInt32(fileSizeValue))
```

**And the Function to Calculate the Size of Video:**

```
func getVideoSize(contentUrl:URL) -> UInt64{
    do {
        let fileAttribute: [FileAttributeKey : Any] = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: contentUrl.path)
        if let fileNumberSize: NSNumber = fileAttribute[FileAttributeKey.size] as? NSNumber {
            return UInt64(truncating: fileNumberSize)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
   return 0
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Code which i used earlier and works fine for me. Try this

```
let account = ACAccountStore()
            let accountType = account.accountType(
                withAccountTypeIdentifier: ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter)

            account.requestAccessToAccounts(with: accountType, options: nil,
                                            completion: {(success, error) in

                                                if success {
                                                    let arrayOfAccounts =
                                                        account.accounts(with: accountType)

                                                    if (arrayOfAccounts?.count)! > 0 {
                                                        let twitterAccount = arrayOfAccounts?.last as! ACAccount
                                                        let message = “your text here”
                                                        print(twitterAccount)


                                                        self.socialVideo.uploadTwitterVideo(self.coachController?.videoData as Data!, comment: message, account: twitterAccount, withCompletion: { (success, value) in


                                                            if success == true {

                                                                self.showToast(message: "Uploaded Succesfully")
                                                            }

                                                        })
                                                    }
                                                }
            })
```

link to download SocialVideo Helper -> https://github.com/liu044100/SocialVideoHelper

Comment: You have not included the function self.socialVideo.uploadTwitterVideo() which you have used to upload the video.

Comment: you have to download SocialVideoHelper (objective-c) files in your code to use this.

Comment: Can you please edit the answer and post the link to that please.

Comment: Done. Please check and let me know if it works. Thanks

Comment: Some how it worked for me, but not in my case. Any ways thanks for the answer. Really appreciated your effort with an up vote.